# Inner Pages are not opening after changing the domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have changed the domain name from sportautolegend.com to sportautonext.com the same code,and I have changed the server. Now inner pages are giving this error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /car-listing-per-brand/40517374805_AC was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Only home page and major inner pages are opening.I need some help please.

Comment: without seeing any code, no idea

Answer (score 0):

If its a wordpress website then you will need to login to wordpress admin and in the settings fix the General settings and permalinks with the correct domain name